# What is the fastest way to insert record in SQL Server from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have 5 tables, for each table i want to delete data and insert 100 records.
all operation should happen in single transaction.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with your work so far.

Answer (score 3):

In real terms, 100 records is not much; if performance is your aim, you could *try* using `SqlBulkCopy` - this uses raw TDS, and supports transactions via the optional [constructor argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wftd1yfz(v=vs.110).aspx). In terms of how to feed data in: `SqlBulkCopy` accepts either `DataTable` or a data reader; "FastMember" allows you to treat a `List<T>` or similar as a data-reader, if that helps (see example at the [bottom of this page](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member)). However, you should be careful to actually time that against doing the same thing with regular parameterized TSQL operations, as for a number like 100 it isn't *guaranteed* that `SqlBulkCopy` would be faster.

---

An alternative to `SqlBulkCopy` would be "table valued parameters"; this requires more config, as the user type needs to be defined on the server etc, but; it can work.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Marc Gravell, Correct 100 records for each table are not much,but in my case each second will have 10 to 20 request to delete and insert records from those table. I tried parameterized query but i am not happy with the performance. In case of SqlBulkCopy for each table request will hit the database (correct me if i am wrong) which i want to avoid.

Comment: @SyedQayyum yes, `SqlBulkCopy` would be 5 round trips for 5 tables. That's ... actually pretty good. You **could try** a single operation using "table valued parameters", but that would be some **really really** ugly SQL.